# Can not update spreadsheet with Exact Online formulas of Invantive Control

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control, exact-online

When I open a spreadsheet with formulas on Exact Online, I get the following error:

[image: Excel error message]

(In English: a number of links can not be updated. You can proceed without updating the values or by editing the incorrect links)

When I edit the links, I see a link to the folder `c:\users\gle3\appdata\romaing\microsoft\addins` with the file `Invantive Control functions.xlam`, which is not present on my PC.

Also, the spreadsheet says that is in protected mode:

[image: Excel in protected mode]

Even when I leave protected, I can not update the financial information taken from Exact Online with formulas.

The formulas are also weird, like for instance:

```
='C:\Users\gle3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Invantive Control functions.xlam'!I_EOL_BAL_PDER_CLASSIFICATION($A9;eolfinyearprev;periodstart;periodend;eolreportingschemecode;"003";;1) + 'C:\Users\gle3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Invantive Control functions.xlam'!I_EOL_BAL_PDER_CLASSIFICATION($A9;eolfinyearprev;periodstart;periodend;eolreportingschemecode;"0030";;1) + 'C:\Users\gle3\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Invantive Control functions.xlam'!I_EOL_BAL_PDER_CLASSIFICATION($A9;eolfinyearprev;periodstart;periodend;eolreportingschemecode;"0031";;1)
```

where I would expect just:

```
I_EOL_BAL_PDE_R_CLASSIFICATION(...) + ...
```

How can I update the financial information?

Answer (score 0):

Please see last picture (Excel in protected mode). The Excel add-in Invantive Control is missing.

Please install it first from download.invantive.com. WHen you restart Excel fully, it will be listed in the ribbon.

And when you open a spreadsheet with formulas, it will automatically rewrite the links to point to your local XLAM.